# How to change loading gif of AsyncImage

Tags: python, kivy

As per my Kivy App below for loading gif, I'm trying to set the image I wanted. I have done lots of research but couldn't find it. I found a thing such as "loading image", however it's not working, or I've misapplied. Can you help me please? Thanks for your help at the moment.

```
from kivy.app import App
#from kivy.uix.image import AsyncImage
from kivy.lang import Builder
kv = """
BoxLayout:
    AsyncImage:
        source: "http://wallpaper-gallery.net/images/wallpaper-for-android/wallpaper-for-android-24.jpg"
        size_hint_y: None
        keep_ratio: False
        allow_stretch: True
"""
class gif_deneme(App):
    def build(self):
        a = Builder.load_string(kv)
        return a
gif_deneme().run()
```

If you couldn't understand,look this:

[image]

I'm trying to change default loading gif of AsyncImage.

Namely,in this image,default loading gif is below:

[image]

But for example,i want to this loading gif:

[image]

Can i solve this problem?

Comment: I really thank you for your settings.I couldn't show codes well.

Comment: Probably i couldn't tell my problem,you're correct,too.I changed title of this subject.Title is "how to change loading gif of AsyncImage.I'm going to edit this title.

Comment: If you can not upload an image for your reputation, then you can use one thing: it gains reputation, I recommend you read: [What is reputation? How do I earn (and lose) it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)

Comment: Or upload it somewhere else and attach the link.

Comment: If you change the extensions of those images to .png, .jpg could place it directly. webp is not supported by SO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Change Default Loading Image

To change the default loading image to your loading image use *Loader.loading_image = 'loading.png'*. Please refer to the example below for details.

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.loader import Loader
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv = """
BoxLayout:
    AsyncImage:
        source: "http://wallpaper-gallery.net/images/wallpaper-for-android/wallpaper-for-android-24.jpg"
        keep_ratio: True
        allow_stretch: True
"""


class gif_deneme(App):
    def build(self):
        Loader.loading_image = 'loading.gif'
        a = Builder.load_string(kv)
        return a


gif_deneme().run()
```

## Output

[image: Img01 - Loading Image]
[image: Img02 - Image Loaded]

Comment: Unfortunately,thing i research isn't keep_raito or allow_stretch.But your every answer can develop me and another person.even so i learnt.

Comment: I have updated my post to show how to change the default loading image to the image you wnat.

Comment: I 'm very sorry.I was late.I became very happy for your interest.I thank for your help.You obliged me really.